# Tools and software to visualize the moving cell compartments in 3D

Tags: protein-structure, 3d-structure

[Also asked on biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/9589316/)

I am looking for tools and software that could help me visualize moving cell compartments in 3D where I can go from the cell membrane to the ER, then out with the protein into the matrix. In short a 3D visualization of the cell environment.

Since I am a newbie, I would appreciate any tool/software suggestion for me to try.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.